# RIP Terry Pratchett

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

I'm incredibly sad to find out Terry Pratchett, possibly my favorite fantasy author, finally passed away. Went into the endless desert. Left early to avoid the rush. Kicked the bucket.

I find this passage relevant:

> ‘Goodbye,’ Mort said, and was surprised to find a lump in his throat.  ‘It’s such an unpleasant word, isn’t it?’
>
> QUITE SO.  Death grinned because, as has so often been remarked, he didn’t have much option.  But possibly he meant it, this time.
>
> I PREFER AU REVOIR, he said.

Comment: One of my most favourite authors of all time. I has a sad.

Comment: I've just been rereading *Truckers*, logged into SFF.SE, and found this. Very sad.

Comment: I hope this question is as popular as the Leonard Nimoy one! We mustn't forget the fantasy part of SFF.

Comment: Death isn't cruel - merely terribly, terribly good at his job.

Answer (score 49):

From his official twitter feed:

[image: "AT LAST SIR TERRY WE MUST WALK TOGETHER"]

Answer (score 32):

> "No one is actually dead until the ripples they cause in the world die away..."
>
> Terry Pratchett, "Reaper Man"

R.I.P Mr. Pratchett. You and your celestial turtle A'tuin shall live in our hearts forever.

Answer (score 21):

> 'But he can't die! He's always been here!' said Gurder, aghast. 'You've got it wrong. Sir? Sir!'
>
> [...]
>
> 'Is he dead?' 
>  '*I detect no life functions.*' 
>  'What does that mean?' 
>  '*It means "yes".*'
>
> [...]
>
> 'It has pleased Arnold Bros (est. 1905) to take our brother to the great Gardening Department beyond Consumer Accounts, where there is Ideal Lawn Edging and an Amazing Floral Display and the pool of eternal life in Easy-to-Lay Polythene with Real Crazy-Paving Edging.'

**R. I. P.**

Answer (score 16):

I'm reading Reaper Man right now, for the first time. It was given to me be a friend, and its my first Pratchett novel.

Incredibly odd and bittersweet for him to have died while I was reading *this* book. Reaper Man was already on its way to becoming one of my favorites prior to the news the other day. We humans love to find significance in odd timing, but this a moment which will stick with me.

Terry Pratchett gave a great deal to the world. I feel lucky to benefit from a little of it.

Answer (score 9):

- [Tribute by Irregular Webcomics](http://www.irregularwebcomic.net/3375.html)
- [Tribute by xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com/1498/)

In addition, [the L-space Web, a homepage that collects information about Terry Pratchett and his writings,](https://www.lspace.org/) has added a landing page with an obituary, and moved the old main page a click below that.

Answer (score 8):

[GNU Terry Pratchett](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/books/booknews/11474455/Terry-Pratchett-will-live-on-in-the-clacks-thanks-to-fans-programming-code.html)

Answer (score 5):

This video is very relevant.

Answer (score -3):

I quote his line about cats not having forgotten that they were once worshipped as gods. Anyone with a beautiful female cat sees how apt this is -- I never met a creature who clearly thought she was the center of the world.